# Stopping an action that is set to happen at a certain time interval

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am making a "Match-3" type game with a "playing card" twist.

Background info, not relevant -> The game is a twist on the game Scat (or 31). The objective is making sets of 3 cards of the same suit with the Ace being worth 11 (thus 31 being the highest score).

I've got the game working great, with combos and chains happening after cards are removed and new cards fall into place.

My next objective is to let the player know of a possible "swap" after a few seconds since the last swap, and then every 2 seconds after that until a swap is made. I decided to make the cards "shake" for half a second and it looks great.

My problem is that once the swap occurs, and the removing/falling/replacing animations begin, the "unused" card in the swap keeps shaking and it is especially noticeable when large combos occur and this one little card keeps shaking every two seconds!

I realize there are a thousand ways to deal with this, but I seriously haven't came across a good one! Here are my relevant functions:

```
- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast
{
    self.lastSwapTimeInterval += timeSinceLast;

    if (self.lastSwapTimeInterval > 2)
    {
        self.lastSwapTimeInterval = 0;
        [self showPossibleSwap];
    }
}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
    self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

    if (timeSinceLast > 1)
    {
        timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0;
        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
    }

    [self updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:timeSinceLast];
}

-(void)animatePossibleSwap:(BGSSwap *)swap
{
    BGSCard *first = swap.cardA;
    BGSCard *second = swap.cardB;

    const NSTimeInterval timeDiff = 0.05;

    SKAction *rot15r = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-[self degreesToRadian:15] duration:0.05];
    SKAction *rot30 = [SKAction rotateByAngle:[self degreesToRadian:30] duration:0.1];
    SKAction *rot30r = [SKAction rotateByAngle:-[self degreesToRadian:30] duration:0.1];

    [first.sprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[rot15r,rot30,rot30r,rot30,rot15r]]];
    [second.sprite runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:timeDiff],rot15r,rot30,rot30r,rot30,rot15r]]];
}

-(void)showPossibleSwap
{
    BGSSwap *swap = [self.level.possibleSwaps anyObject];

    [self animatePossibleSwap:swap];

    NSLog(@"Show Possible Swap NOW: %f",_lastSwapTimeInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `withKey :` on your shake SKActions to give each animation a name. You can then use `removeActionforKey:` when you decide that the animation in no longer applicable.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I had found this method but have been scouring my code for a good place to implement it... most likely should be in a completion block right?

Comment: I guess you'll want to stop the shake animation when you do the swap - sometime you need to take a step back from the details of your code and think about a what you're trying to achieve.